# Xdebug stops on xdebug_break() but not on breakpoints in NetBeans

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, xdebug

I am trying to use Xdebug in combination with NetBeans to debug my PHP code.
And it is already working as expected when setting a `xdebug_break()` statement within my code, i.e. the execution stops at the line after it.

Though it does not work when I set a breakpoint for a line within the NetBeans UI.

My configuration looks like this:

**Programs:**

- NetBeans 8.1
- Xdebug 2.4.1 (Thread Safe, 64-bit)
- PHP 5.6.26 (Thread Safe, 64-bit)

**Configuration:**

php.ini

```ini
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.idekey = NetBeans
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 1024
```

NetBeans:

[image: NetBeans PHP debugging configuration]

[image: NetBeans project run configuration]

[image: NetBeans advanced web configuration]

So, why does `xdebug_break()` work but not the breakpoints?

Comment: if you run your page with "XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug" parameters does it help? like this http://localhost/?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug

Comment: NetBeans does that automatically when I click the *Debug Project* button. Note that my IDE key is called "NetBeans"; so the page is called with `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=NetBeans` as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the reason for this unexpected behavior was that the project URL in the run configuration was wrong. The *Project URL* field actually requires to set the project's **root URL** and the *Index File* field takes the index file **path**.

So, instead of writing this:

Project URL: `http://localhost/project_name/some/path/`
Index File: `index.php`

I had to write this:

Project URL: `http://localhost/project_name/`
Index File: `some/path/index.php`